# Pass every excel file in python from assigning a specific name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following excel files in a directory:

excel_sheet_01

excel_sheet_02

.
.
.

excel_sheet_nm

How can I do using pandas, that every excel sheet gets stored in a dataframe variable whose name
corresponds to the two last digits. i.e.  I would get in python the following variables:

01

02

...

nm

Thank you so much

Comment: You can save it like df01, df02 .... but not simply as 01, 02. As per rules, variable names cannot start with number.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that!

Comment: But I am mostly interested in how to read all af the files and assign them a name that is included in the file name, the specific name is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to type out every single variable (and especially if you have unknown number of files) you could think of storing the DataFrames in a List (or Dict). something like:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
excel_sheets = [f.name for f in os.scandir(path) if not f.is_dir() and 'excel_sheet' in f.name]

my_dataframes = []
for f in excel_sheets:
    my_dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(f))

my_dataframes_dict = {}
for f in excel_sheets:
    my_dataframes_dict.update({f: pd.read_excel(f)})
```

In the case of the list you can access it through the index. In the case of the dictionary you can choose whatever (unique) name you want.

Comment: you probably need `pd.read_excel`, not `pd.read_csv`,  but yes this should be the approach

Comment: yes, very true! just copy pasted from snippet. I will edit it in the answer.